# How add simple product SKU to grouped products table?

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

How do you add the simple product sku to the grouped product table?

Basically, I want to remove the grouped product sku and add the sku's to each simple product that are listed in the grouped product table.  See the image below and the red drawing for a visual of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: What about adding the simple product description or short description to each line as well as the SKU. $_item->getDescription or $_item->getShortDescription don't appear to exist/work. Additionally is there a way to see which methods are available for $_item and possibly add getDescription to the class?

Comment: you can post new question for this

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153630)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the below file:

> vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

To:

> app/design/Vendor/Theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

And add the below code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <th class="col sku" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Sku') ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sku')) ?>" class="col sku">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                    <div class="control qty">
                        <input type="number"
                               name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                               data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>
```

Comment: This worked for the grouped products table. The only other thing is how to remove the sku under the product title when it is a grouped product only (that sku is not used so its not useful to display it).

Comment: Do you want to remove that sku only for group products? Can you add one new question for that?